# When submitting page to google form it will print the result then redirect to home page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, printing

There is 3 things i want it to do

1. Submit to Google form. = redirecting me to Google Form
2. Print this page. = when i click Print or Cancel to print page it will then
3. Redirect me to another page witch is the Home Page

I am using this code and it works sometimes the problem is when i click on submit i get 2 popup's First popup with on error saying "Some printing function are disabled" On click ok redirects me to page 1.  second popup window is the printing msg witch ask me to print, when hitting print redirects me to page 2. so saying that it works, but because of that error msg if i click it to fast or if i click on the print button first, it wont redirect me as i wanted to.  How should i deal with this?

Here is the code i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     <!-- Print & Submit page -->
     function Submit_print_google()  { 
         window.print();        
         // Google form
         var formElementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('FORM');
         if ( formElementsArray != null ) {
            var formElement = formElementsArray[0];
            document.getElementById('Google_form').name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';
            formElement.action = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/formResponse';  
            window.location = 'http://link.com/HomePage';
            formElement.submit();   
         } else {
            redirect();
         }
     }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">  
     function redirect(){   
         document.location = "http://link.com/homepage" }
     }  
 </script> 

 <form id="Google_form"  action="JavaScript:Submit_print_google()" 
method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_self" autocomplete="off" 
onsubmit="window.location = 'JavaScript:Submit_print_google()';">

      First name<input name="entry.1234567789"  class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1234567789"  type="text">
      Last Name<input name="entry.123456" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_123456" type="text" >
      <input type="submit" style="float:right" value="Submit & Print Page" >
```

Update This code works when i click cancel job for the print but wont work when i click print. I need it to work on both on cancel and print.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!-- Print & Submit page -->
function Submit_print_google()  {                   

    // Google form
  var formElementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('FORM');
  if (formElementsArray != null) {
    var formElement = formElementsArray[0];
      document.getElementById('Google_form').name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';
      formElement.action = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/xxx/formResponse';  
      formElement.submit();
      // Redirect
      redirect()}
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 // Redirect
 function redirect()
 {window.print(); 
 window.location = 'http://www.link.com/HomePage.html'; }
 </script>
```

I even tryid this. But nothing will work only on cancell

```
function redirect(){       
     if (window.print()) {
        window.location = 'http://www.link.com/Home.page.html';
    } else {
        window.location = 'http://www.link.com/Home.page.html';
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code? Of course your not being re-directed properly.
window.location = 'http:// Page 1 HomePage';
document.location = "http:// Page 1 HomePage"
these both are non-existing urls.

May I note your code isn't valid. In your redirect function, you forgot the semicolon after setting a variable. You as well closed the function twice with the closing char "}".

Comment: No those "http:// Page 1 HomePage" is a link i just changed the url so for everyone to understand the link redirection.

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is when a customer comes in to my store. thy fill out the forms it should print the result then submit the page to google forms.      anyway i just fix the closed tag and i have a updated script i will add it here. everything works but now on print it wont work only on cancel

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the print url in a new tab/window.
Redirect the current page to the url you are trying to redirect them to.

I believe the problem you are having is that the same page is trying to handle both the printing and the redirection; which is impossible to to both in one page. Therefor, only when you cancel the printing will the redirection work.

The code Should go something like this:

```
window.open('http://www.link.com/Home.page.html','_blank');
```

Comment: Yep this will help by opening in a new window. is it possible to be open in the same window?

Comment: It depends on the clients computer if it will open in a new tab or new window. You cannot control that.

Comment: I mean it should open in the same window like window.location dose.